# Why Reactjs mqtt client url return wss?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mqtt

The code below work well when used `node client_test.js`. But when I put this to reactjs I get this error:

> (unknown) WebSocket connection to 'wss://dev.xxx.com:8083/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

This URL always convert to `wss` protocol. I don't know why this happens.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

var options = {
  //port: 8083,
  //host: 'dev.xxx.com',
  clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
  username: 'xxx',
  password: new Buffer('xxx'),
  keepalive: 10,
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
  protocolVersion: 3,
  clean: true,
  encoding: 'utf8',
  //protocol: 'mqtts',
  rejectUnauthorized : false,    
  will: {
    topic: 'node/status',
    payload: new Buffer('offline')
  }
};

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtts://dev.xxx.com:8083', options)

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ReactJS runs in the browser, the browser sandbox only allows it to make ws(s) connections not raw socket connections required for native MQTT.

The mqtt library is automatically converting the URL to one it can try and use in the browser (namely a secure websocket connection)

You'll need to make sure your broker supports Secure Websockets connections if you want to use it with ReactJS

Comment: Thanks, @hardillb useful answer